# How can I implement a native custom submenu with electron in render process

Tags: menu, electron, contextmenu

I want to implement a native submenu with electron like this.

[image: 5d10c9101610e51113]

I look all of https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu, but I can't find anything about custom menu with electron, how I do next? I have no idea.

Comment: I haven't researched this enough for a full answer, but you need to consider the possibility that this is not implemented in Electron. To find out, you should probably first find the exact terms to describe this feature in the macOS/.. world, which is useful for devs to pin down what it is you need, and then inquire over at Electron's GitHub issues etc.

Comment: @snwflk thank you. I think so, and I will to find this feature in theh macOS.